# Serious answers to Purim Torah questions

Tags: discussion, purim-torah-policy

When a question is marked as being Purim Torah, is it okay to respond with a serious answer, such as [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/55433/4704)?

Comment: Good question, but I don't think the example you link to is a good example: its author says (in a comment there) it was meant as a joke.

Comment: What about [Meta PTIJ](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3479/5323)?

Answer (score 3):

(I don't think the post you link to in the question is a good example of what you're asking about, inasmuch as its author says, in a comment there, that it's meant as a joke. In any event:)

No, a serious answer to a Purim Torah question is not addressing the question as asked (viz with [the PTIJ disclaimer](/q/797)) or as intended. Thus, it's not an answer.

Comment: Can you incorporate a suggested comment template explaining this to well-meaning answerers?